# How to create a structured card - multi select checklist with dynamic values in LivePerson

Tags: liveperson

I want to show case a multi-select checklist of items, where the array of item values are stored in a variable in pre-process code. How can I display these values as the checklist in universal interaction dynamically. which means sometimes the array may contain 2 items for check list, sometimes the array may contain 5 items as checklist options.

For example: var items = [{NJPW, WWE, ROH, CMLL}] the items need to be displayed in checklist as below

[image]

if the items are 6 then the checklist should be able to display dynamic 6 options as below. how can I create a universal interaction for those dynamic values?